# Max customer order quantity, spend limit per month

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, customer, magento-ce

I want to apply restrictions for customers. A customer can have  maximum 99 orders per month and the total monthly purchase limit should be 500$.Any help.

Comment: You really should try to explain more about what you have tried up to this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short question, short answer.

First: If you allow guest orders, this doesn't make sense, just for the case.

You could check with an observer against the orders who one customer made, but I think this is pretty slow to sum up all the orders by one customer all the time.

- So I would add two new attributes to the customer (one to count the
  order, one to sum the grand total), implement an observer for adding
  a new order and update the two attributes.
- Implement a second observer to check,  e.g. in    `controller_action_predispatch` if the customer already reach the limit and add a message, so he knows.
- Implement a third observer e.g. in `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index` and redirect the customer to wherever to don't allow him to checkout, maybe add a second error message.
- Implement a cron to reset the attributes every first of the month